# How to solve this problem (throw an exception)

Tags: c, pointers, exception, operator-precedence, dereference

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_count(int*);
int* input_values(int);
void show_result(int**, int);

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    input_count(&count);
    int* array = input_values(count);
    show_result(&array, count);
    return 0;
}

void input_count(int* count)
{
    do
    {
        printf("배열의 개수는? (0보다 커야합니다) ");
        scanf("%d", count);
    } while (*count <= 0);
}
int* input_values(int count)
{
    int* array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d번째 값은? ", i);
        scanf("%d", array + i);
    }
    return array;
}
void show_result(int** array, int count)
{
    int max = 0, min = INT_MAX;

    int* max_address = NULL, *min_address = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (*array[i] > max)
        {
            max_address = *array + i;
            max = *max_address;
        }
        if (*array[i] < min)
        {
            min_address = *array + i;
            min = *min_address;
        }
    }
    printf("최대 원소의 주소: %p, 값: %d\n", max_address, max);
    printf("최소 원소의 주소: %p, 값: %d\n", min_address, min);
}
```

I've only been studying programming for 10 days, so my skills are lacking. But I want to solve this problem.

The show_result function throws an exception:

> Exception thrown(0x00007FF6BE02596B, Main.exe): 0xC0000005: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 위치를 읽는 동안 액세스 위반이 발생했습니다.

Images:

[image]

[image]

I think Null is the problem, but I don't know the mean that is back reference.

Comment: not getting any errors when adding, `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: You have too much indirection with `show_result(&array, count);` and `void show_result(int** array, int count)`. The array is not an array of pointers.

Comment: Minor: `int max = 0` should be `int max = INT_MIN`.

Comment: Assuming you fix your indirection problem, neither `max` nor `min` are even necessary. Think about what `min_address` and `max_address` should both point to prior to entering your loop. That should assist in understanding why `min` and `max` are superfluous.

Comment: `*array[i]` is the same as `*(array[i])` which is not what you want. You want `(*array)[i]`. That said .... why pass `&array` to `show_result` ? Just pass `array` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sense to pass the pointer to the dynamically allocated array by reference through a pointer to it

```
show_result(&array, count);
```

because the pointer is not changed within the function show_result.

So declare the function like

```
void show_result( const int *, size_t );
```

and call it like

```
show_result( array, count);
```

The if statements

```
    if (*array[i] > max)
```

and

```
    if (*array[i] < min)
```

use invalid expressions. You have to write at least like

```
    if ( ( *array )[i] > max)
```

and

```
    if ( ( *array )[i] < min)
```

You will not have such a problem if will declare the function as shown above.

Also setting the variable `max` to `0`

```
int max = 0, min = INT_MAX;
```

does not make sense. As the element type of the array is `int` then it can contain all elements set by negative numbers. In this case you will get a wrong result.

The function can be defined for example the following way

```
void show_result( const int *array, size_t count) 
{
    const int *max_address = array; 
    const int *min_address = array;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i )
    {
        if ( *max_address < array[i] )
        {
            max_address = array + i;
        }
        else if ( array[i] < *min_address )
        {
            min_address = array + i;
        }
    }

    if ( count != 0 )
    {
        printf( "최대 원소의 주소: %p, 값: %d\n", ( const void * )max_address, *max_address );
        printf( "최소 원소의 주소: %p, 값: %d\n", ( const void * )min_address, *min_address );
    }
    else
    {
        // output a message that an empty array is passed 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir. i love you
i want to use double pointer.
but you know me only use single pointer.
have a nice day

Comment: if i use const as parameter, that makes error.
i try erase the const.
not error

Comment: @프린이 The function should be compiled with the qualifier const of its first parameter.

Comment: i understand and solve it!
thankyou thankyou
good night!